# Fullcalendar filter by className

Tags: jquery, filter, fullcalendar, classname

I've set up multiple select filters for my Fullcalendar project. I can filter by several event values in my JSON, but I can't get it to filter by `className`.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code I'm using and [here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/kzfwro22/) that replicates the issue.

```
<select id="type_selector">
    <option value="all">All types</option>
    <option value="university">University</option>
    <option value="polytech">Polytech</option>
    <option value="highschool">High School</option>
</select>
<select id="state_selector">
    <option value="all">All types</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
</select>
<select id="color_selector">
    <option value="all">All colors</option>
    <option value="red">Red schools</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange schools</option>
    <option value="green">Green schools</option>
</select>
<div>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,

            year: 2016,
            month: 08,
            date: 25,

            slotMinutes: 15,
            editable: true,

            events: [{
                title: 'Michigan University',
                start: '2016-09-26',
                type: 'university',
                state: 'MI',
                className: 'red'
            }, {
                title: 'California Polytechnic',
                start: '2016-09-27',
                type: 'polytech',
                state: 'CA',
                className: 'orange'
            }, {
                title: 'Vermont University',
                start: '2016-09-28',
                type: 'university',
                state: 'VT',
                className: 'red'
            }, {
                title: 'Michigan High School',
                start: '2016-09-29',
                type: 'highschool',
                state: 'MI',
                className: 'green'
            }, {
                title: 'Vermont High School',
                start: '2016-09-30',
                type: 'highschool',
                state: 'VT',
                className: 'green'
            }, {
                title: 'California High School',
                start: '2016-09-30',
                type: 'highschool',
                state: 'CA',
                className: 'green'
            }],
            eventRender: function eventRender(event, element, view) {
                return ['all', event.type].indexOf($('#type_selector').val()) >= 0
                && ['all', event.state].indexOf($('#state_selector').val()) >= 0
                && ['all', event.className].indexOf($('#color_selector').val()) >= 0 
            }

        });
        $('#type_selector').on('change', function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
        })
        $('#state_selector').on('change', function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
        })
        $('#color_selector').on('change', function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
        }) 
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the name "className". [`className` is a DOM property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp) so, when you try to access `event.className` you're not actually accessing the event's property (the red, orange, etc) but the DOM property, which is returning something like `['red']`.

If you change the className to any other (non-reserved, non-property), that should be fixed (check [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/kzfwro22/1/)).

Of course, this means the background color of each event now goes back to the default blue. You can fix this by setting the properties `backgroundColor` and `borderColor` (check the [`Event Object` documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/#color-options)), as such:

```
events: [{
    title: 'Michigan University',
    start: '2016-09-26',
    type: 'university',
    state: 'MI',
    cName: 'red',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    borderColor: 'red'
}]
```

You can simplify all this and simply replace `className` for `backgroundColor` since this property returns a string with the background color name (which matches your select options).

So you would end up with something like this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/kzfwro22/2/)):

```
<select id="type_selector">
    <option value="all">All types</option>
    <option value="university">University</option>
    <option value="polytech">Polytech</option>
    <option value="highschool">High School</option>
</select>
<select id="state_selector">
    <option value="all">All types</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
    <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
</select>
<select id="color_selector">
    <option value="all">All colors</option>
    <option value="red">Red schools</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange schools</option>
    <option value="green">Green schools</option>
</select>
<div>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>

<script>

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,

        year: 2016,
        month: 8,
        date: 25,

        slotMinutes: 15,
        editable: true,

        events: [{
            title: 'Michigan University',
            start: '2016-09-26',
            type: 'university',
            state: 'MI',
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            borderColor: 'red'
        }, {
            title: 'California Polytechnic',
            start: '2016-09-27',
            type: 'polytech',
            state: 'CA',
            backgroundColor: 'orange',
            borderColor: 'orange'
        }, {
            title: 'Vermont University',
            start: '2016-09-28',
            type: 'university',
            state: 'VT',
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            borderColor: 'red'
        }, {
            title: 'Michigan High School',
            start: '2016-09-29',
            type: 'highschool',
            state: 'MI',
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            borderColor: 'green'
        }, {
            title: 'Vermont High School',
            start: '2016-09-30',
            type: 'highschool',
            state: 'VT',
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            borderColor: 'green'
        }, {
            title: 'California High School',
            start: '2016-09-30',
            type: 'highschool',
            state: 'CA',
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            borderColor: 'green'
        }],
        eventRender: function eventRender(event, element, view) {
            return ['all', event.type].indexOf($('#type_selector').val()) >= 0
                && ['all', event.state].indexOf($('#state_selector').val()) >= 0
                && ['all', event.backgroundColor].indexOf($('#color_selector').val()) >= 0;
        }

    });
    $('#type_selector').on('change', function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
    });
    $('#state_selector').on('change', function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
    });
    $('#color_selector').on('change', function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
    });
</script>
```

---

There is another way, without changing the code too much, but you'll need to be careful with this. Since `event.className` is returning an array with the name of the class, you could just change

```
eventRender: function eventRender(event, element, view) {
    return ['all', event.type].indexOf($('#type_selector').val()) >= 0
        && ['all', event.state].indexOf($('#state_selector').val()) >= 0
        && ['all', event.className].indexOf($('#color_selector').val()) >= 0 
}
```

To

```
eventRender: function eventRender(event, element, view) {
    return ['all', event.type].indexOf($('#type_selector').val()) >= 0
        && ['all', event.state].indexOf($('#state_selector').val()) >= 0
        && ['all', event.className[0]].indexOf($('#color_selector').val()) >= 0 
}
```

Note the `[0]` in front of `event.className`. This way, you'll compare the option value with the first class name.

You'll need to be careful, because if you have more than one class, the first element might not be the value of the select options.

Check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzfwro22/5/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @milz !!! I was wondering if I could use a json neutral array property, like "myClass", and get FullCalendar to call it also for "className"?  Or could I use the official DOM property "className" and also assign its value to a neutral variable "myClass" and then call the neutral variable from my return routine?  I'm trying to keep the data entry process as short as possible.

Comment: @lbriquet You won't be able to use just the neutral property because you'll loose the background color. You can, however, set the `className` for the styles and set `myClass` for the filtering. Take a look at [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/kzfwro22/4/)

Comment: Thank you again for your help @milz!  What I was hoping to do is to do something like var myClass = event.className... and then use it with the return ['all', event.myClass].indexOf($('#color_selector').val()) >= 0  Is this possible?

Comment: @lbriquet Oh, I see what you mean. I've edited the answer and added another way at the end of the answer, where you only need to change a small thing on the original code.

Comment: Perfect!!  :)  Thank you so much @milz