# View a specific category in Fullcalendar which is checked and hide other events

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, fullcalendar

I have made an awesome [Fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) coding which is able to fetch events from MySQL database and view the events in Fullcallendar page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '2016-01-12',
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [
        <?php foreach($events as $event): 

            $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
            $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
            if($start[1] == '00:00:00'){
                $start = $start[0];
            }else{
                $start = $event['start'];
            }
            if($end[1] == '00:00:00'){
                $end = $end[0];
            }else{
                $end = $event['end'];
            }
        ?>
            {
                id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
                title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
                start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
                end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
                color: '<?php echo $event['color']; ?>',
            },
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        ]
    });
});
```

and view it in `<div id="calendar"></div>`

### It is so nice and easy to use, and if you like you can use it. :)

Now I have a new idea to implement, but didn't succeed. I tried different tutorials.

The cause of this idea is this that sometimes the calendar is full of events and it is a bit annoying, so i wanted to somehow filter it. Like i have three check boxes beside the calendar i.e.

1. Birthdays
2. Holidays
3. Events

and view only the checked events i.e. just `birthdays` and `holidays` or only `events` or `events` and `holiday`, and hide the unchecked events.

For this i have a column in my database by the name of `categories`, and every event category is listed there.

So my question is that is there any way to filter the events by their category and view them in Fullcalendar and hide the unchecked events.

Comment: For one of my project I am creating the events through ajax, there are many complications involved in my requirement if you want then I can share the ajax method with you or else you can do it using classes the attribute for that is "  className: eventClass", you can pass classes to each event type and then on click of checkboxes, play with jquery hide/show.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Actually it doesn't matter because we just want to learn and share knowledge. Just provide as a working solution. Thanks

Comment: Dear @RohitAilani i think using the Ajax method might be easier.

Comment: See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kzfwro22/5/). This question is very close duplicate with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39769761/908174).

Comment: Dear milz, that question is based on data on the page which is entered manually, but I want the data to be taken from MySQL database and view them into the calendar.